# Replace files smaller than 1KB from backup

Tags: windows, backup, powershell, robocopy

I need to use backups to replace corrupted files on a shared folder. All corrupted files are fixed size = 1KB and have the archive flag set.  Basically, I'd like to replace files in the destination folder with files from backups only if the destination file is <= 1KB and/or has the archive flag set.

Robocopy looks like a possible tool for this, but I can't see an option to condition it on the destination file.  Another tool that looks like it might do this is Powershell, but I am unfamiliar with it.

How can I accomplish this with either program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell solution, can report and\or restore corrupted files:

```powershell
# Use full paths!
$Backup = '\\server\backup'
$Corrupted = 'c:\broken_folder'

# Path for log file, can be relative
$LogFile = '.\Restore.log'

# If this variable is set to true, no files will be copied
$ReportOnly = $true

# Remove log file, if exist
if(Test-Path -Path $LogFile -PathType Leaf)
{
    Remove-Item -Path $LogFile -Force
}

# Get all files in directory, recursive
$Corrupted | Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    # Select files with archive attribute: $_.Mode -like '*a*'
    # And size less or equal to 1KB: ($_.Length / 1KB) -le 1 . Less fancy way: $_.Length -le 1024
    # Ignore folders: -not $_.PsIsContainer
    #
    # In PS 3.0 and higher Get-ChildItem has less cryptic way to get folders and specify attributes:
    # http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/08/27/pstip-how-to-get-only-files-the-powershell-3-0-way
    Where-Object {($_.Mode -like '*a*') -and (($_.Length / 1KB) -le 1) -and (-not $_.PsIsContainer)} |
        ForEach-Object {
            # Output log record to pipeline, Tee-Object will catch it later
            "Found corrupted file: $($_.FullName)"

            # Replace current file path with path fo this file in backup folder
            $NewFile =  $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($Corrupted), $Backup

            if(Test-Path -Path $NewFile -PathType Leaf)
            {
                # Output log record to pipeline, Tee-Object will catch it later
                "Found corresponding file from backup: $NewFile"
            }
            else
            {
                # Output log record to pipeline, Tee-Object will catch it later
                "Failed to find corresponding file from backup: $NewFile"
                return
            }

            if(-not $ReportOnly)
            {
                # Output log record to pipeline, Tee-Object will catch it later
                "Restoring file from backup: $NewFile -> $($_.FullName)"

                # Remove corrupted file
                Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force

                # Copy file from backup
                Copy-Item -Path $NewFile -Destination $_.FullName -Force
            }
        } | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogFile -Append # Send log to screen and file
```

Comment: This is great all working fine, could you tell me how to save report to file, please. I need start learning powershell :)

Comment: @Szafa Sure, see updated answer.

Comment: @Szafa Btw, my script will restore file only if it has size less the 1KB **and** archive flag set. Re-readiing your question, I'm not sure that it's what you've asked for, quote: _file is <= 1KB **and/or** has the archive flag set_. Could you please confirm that you want to restore files that have archive flag set and any files that are less the 1KB, regardless of flags?

Comment: corrupted file is <=1KB and has the archive flag set (corrupted stub file) but your script is not replacing corrupted files from backup, and I can't see why. It is finding corrupted files but not replacing them. I get error : "Found corrupted file: \\server_name\data$\BUSINESS\Management Accounts\2012\01_Month End\11_Nov\00_SAP Month End\CO43 G&A Calc Before ME Nov'12.XLS
Failed to find corresponding file from backup: \\server_name\Restored\Shared\Data\BUSINESS\Management Accounts\2012\01_Month End\11_Nov\00_SAP Month End\CO43 G&A Calc Before ME Nov'12.XLS"

Comment: Could you help, please

Comment: Are you able to Ctrl-C filename `\\server_name\Restored\Shared\Data\BUSINESS\Management Accounts\2012\01_Month End\11_Nov\00_SAP Month End\CO43 G&A Calc Before ME Nov'12.XLS` from log and open it in the Excel using `File->Open->Ctrl+V` ? Just be sure that your eyes don't deceive you and file really exists. I've just checked script with UNC paths and `'` in filename and it works fine for me. Could this be some sort of permissions issue? If anything fails you can try to remove entire `if(Test-Path .... return}` block and see if it helps.

Comment: ok looks like problem is with those corrupted files. i tried to replace them manually with backup once and got error Copying file or folder "the file cannot be accessed by the system" but I can delete corrupted file first and then copy good ones over. Could you add line to remove corrupted file before copying?

Comment: @Szafa Sure, I've updated answer, see if this helps.

Comment: Great all works like a charm. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy has the parameters you need. For example:

/A :: copy only files with the Archive attribute set.

/M :: copy only files with the Archive attribute and reset it.

---

/MAX:n :: MAXimum file size – exclude files bigger than n bytes.

/MIN:n :: MINimum file size – exclude files smaller than n bytes.

Here's a list of all the commands:
https://wmoore.wordpress.com/2009/09/01/robocopy-command-line-switches/